# Enabling cache_classes causes undefined method `increment_counter' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

After upgrade to Rails 3.0.10 I'm getting strange error if I set config.cache_classes=true

`` NoMethodError (undefined method increment_counter' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class):
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/associations.rb:1553:inbelongs_to_counter_cache_after_create_for_form'
  activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in _run_create_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:277:increate'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:257:in create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:increate_or_update'
  activesupport (3.0.10) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:444:in _run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:273:increate_or_update'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:60:in save!'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/validations.rb:49:insave!'
  activerecord (3.0.10) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
  ... ``

I'm saving Answer model which has belongs_to relation with counter cache:

```
belongs_to    :form, :counter_cache => true
```

Strangest thing is that after server restart first save works fine and after that I start getting such exceptions.

Maybe someone could advise where I could start digging for a cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by outdated acts_as_taggable_on_steroids gem which was causing class cache issues with Rails3. Switched to acts-as-taggable-on gem - problem solved.

Comment: Do you happen to know what exactly caused the class cache issue with Rails3? We are suffering from very strange class cache issue right now. Hope you can point it out for me. Thx.